# failing to publish bullseye coverage reports to SonarQube due to source file path changes

Tags: xml, jenkins, sonarqube, bullseye

This image is a part of console output of sonarqube publisher job in jenkins:
[image]

I am trying to publish bullseye coverage reports to sonarqube using analysis parameter as
`sonar.cxx.coverage.reportPath=Coverage.xml`
In the xml file `Coverage.xml`, the bullseye directory and source folder details are as below

```
!-- BullseyeCoverage 8.13.16 Windows x64 License 18830 --
BullseyeCoverage name="Result.cov" dir="c:/work/jenkins/workspace/CirrusFW_BullsEye_Main/" buildId="6861a17e2017-08-03 06:13:18" version="5" xmlns="http://www.bullseye.com/covxml"
fn_cov="54" fn_total="82" cd_cov="117" cd_total="347" d_cov="106" d_total="287"
folder name="Cirrus_FW" fn_cov="54" fn_total="82" cd_cov="117" cd_total="347" d_cov="106" d_total="287"
folder name="Src" fn_cov="54" fn_total="82" cd_cov="117" cd_total="347" d_cov="106" d_total="287"
```

so actual source file path is `c:/work/jenkins/workspace/CirrusFW_BullsEye_Main/Cirrus_FW/Src`

But in the console output, it is searching in the folder
`c:/work/jenkins/workspace/CirrusFW_BullsEye_Main/\Cirrus_FW\Src`

it is adding `/\` (one backslash and one forwardslash) in the path.

How to avoid this as we are not suppose to give that path, it will be taken from Coverage.xml file?

Comment: Could you provide the logs as text instead of an image? This would for example help search engines find this page.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/wiki/Path-and-path-separator-issues) page. Although this is an other context, the rules mentioned could help you.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen Heier, I already referred the page you recommended but in the xml file, we are not suppose to set the path. It will be generated using bullseye command covxml. This path will come from .cov file which will be generated using covmerge command by merging three cov files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a powershell script to rebase the directory which is in that Coverage.xml file